# Does the Galnet news play a part in the game?

Tags: elite-dangerous

[Galnet](http://www.elitedangerous.com/news/galnet/) gives "news" as well as other various information and makes the game feel like its more like a real and breathing place, but does it actually talk about happenings in-game or is it just random flavor to give the game life? Can players affect/change/respond to what happens for Galnet to report on (like destroying a capital ship)?

Comment: With the announcement of the PowerPlay update, I suspect that paying attention to the news will start to be very important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The systems mentioned with conflicts in will contain active conflict zones for players to join in on. If capital ships are mentioned they will be there too.

[Players cannot destroy capital ships but attacking certain sub systems will make them leave (and award the player with credits)](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Farragut#Notes). They will respawn, however.

Player actions can tip a system into civil war or affect the outcome of any system wide conflict.  Significant events are then [reported on GalNet](http://www.elitedangerous.com/news/galnet/?read=13JAN3301fadec3130d8424012aa13e55a7d90206) even when not part of the main story line.

As of 1.04 there are questions as to the efficacy of player actions, [there may be bugs involved](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=97577&page=3&p=1517168#post1517168)

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question I had on what it has to do with Galnet or if players can affect past/present/future articles.

Comment: It's a two way street. Places mentioned will have events there and the outcome of those events will feed back into the story.